# scrolling vs stepping for labelling a large number of things

Tags: labels, scrolling, steps

I'm not sure if this is the correct place to ask this question but I'll try anyway. I have a webapp where the user has to label a large number of separate examples, say 200 of them.  Each example is small enough to easily fit in one page.  My question is this - is it better to

A) Have a "next" and a "previous" button that allows the user to step through these examples as he/she is progressing through the labelling process OR

B) Have all the examples on a single page and the user will progress through the the labelling process by scrolling down.

I was wondering if there was any known rule for one versus the other in this situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each method has advantages:

#### Single Page

- Depending on screen size, the user may be able to avoid an extra click/scroll between items.
- Moving backwards/forwards several items (e.g., "Oh, that last one reminds that I should have done an item quite a while ago differently") can be done with scrolling instead of multiple clicks.

#### Multiple Pages

- Minimize initial page load time.
- A little easier to use (IMHO) on a small/mobile device.